# Insert with id of type serial in pg-promise

Tags: pg-promise

In pg-promise, how can I insert data when the primary key is of type Serial? Omitting the field id creates no response in the call.

The code below produces no error in the catch (and also does not execute the *then* branch).

```
function postSecao(req, res){
  var data = req.body;
  var db = pgp(cn);
  db.none("insert into public.secoes(nome) values($1)", [data.nome])
  .then(function () {
      pgp.end();
      return res.status(201).end();
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(err);
      pgp.end();
      return res.status(500).end();
  });

}
```

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.secoes
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('secoes_id_seq'::regclass),
  nome character varying(100),
  CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Manually providing the id works without problem.

```
function postSecao(req, res){
  var data = req.body;
  var db = pgp(cn);
  db.none("insert into public.secoes(id, nome) values($1,$2)", [data.id, data.nome])
  .then(function () {
      pgp.end();
      return res.status(201).end();
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(err);
      pgp.end();
      return res.status(500).end();
  });

}
```

And of course the SQL runs fine in PGAdmin.

```
insert into public.secoes(nome) values('test')
```

Comment: You will have to rephrase your question and provide any error output from `.catch`, if there is any. The way it is now - just doesn't make sense what you are saying. pg-promise doesn't care about the underlying `serial` type.

Comment: Edited to put more details, hope is better now.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out. The problem was in the privileges control of the user. It is necessary to the user accessing the DB to have privileges over the sequences used in the serial field.

So not a pg-promise problem.

Comment: Looked that was from the beginning (being not related to pg-promise) :) Good you found the problem ;)